# tkinter and python - 1st call of method is ok, second call of method complains that the object doesn't have that attribute

Tags: python, attributes, tkinter

I'm very new to python and tkinter and I'm running into a problem I can't figure out.
I have a button with an associated command that calls a method of my object.
If I press the button I get the results I'm expecting.
If I press the button again I get an error stating:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "LED_GUI_1.py", line 115, in <lambda>
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Red", command= lambda:   Red.set_intensity(float(red_input.get()))).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'set_intensity'
```

I'm thoroughly confused.  Any help is appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#  RGB LED test GUI

from Tkinter import *
import ttk


Red = 0
Green = 0
Blue = 0

def test_pwm_set(channel, intensity):
    global Red, Green, Blue
    print "Calling test_pwm_set"

    if channel == 0:
        Red = intensity
        print "Red = " + str(intensity)
    elif channel == 1:
        Green = intensity
        print "Green = " + str(intensity)
    elif channel == 2:
        Blue = intensity
        print "Blue = " + str(intensity)
    else:
        print 'Invalid Channel!'


def set_red():
    intensity = float(red_input.get())
    print intensity
    print Red.get_intensity()
    Red.set_intensity(50.0)

def set_green():
    intensity = float(green_input.get())
    Green.set_intensity(intensity)

def set_blue():
    intensity = float(blue_input.get())
    Blue.set_intensity(intensity)






class RGB_LED:

    def __init__(self, color, channel, intensity = 0.0):
        self.color = 'color'
        self.channel = channel
        self.intensity = intensity

    def get_channel(self):
        return self.channel

    def get_intensity(self):
        return self.intensity

    def get_color(self):
        return self.color

    def set_channel(self, channel):
        self.channel = channel

    def set_intensity(self, intensity):
        self.intensity = intensity
        test_pwm_set(self.channel, self.intensity)

    def set_color(self, color):
        self.color = 'color'

Red = RGB_LED('Red', 0, 0.0)
Green = RGB_LED('Green', 1, 0.0)
Blue = RGB_LED('Blue', 2, 0.0)



######## set up GUI ##########
root = Tk()
root.title("RGB LED Control")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S)) #frame fills all of root window
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  #tells Tk if root window is resized
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)     #the frame should take up the extra space

#  StringVars
red_input = StringVar()
red_input.set(0.0)
green_input = StringVar()
green_input.set(0.0)
blue_input = StringVar()
blue_input.set(0.0)
red_intensity = StringVar()
green_intensity = StringVar()
blue_intensity = StringVar()

# Entry fields
red_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=red_input)
red_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
green_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=green_input)
green_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
blue_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=blue_input)
blue_entry.grid(column=3, row=2, stick=(W, E))

# Labels
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=red_intensity).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=green_intensity).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=blue_intensity).grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

# Buttons
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Red", command= lambda: Red.set_intensity(float(red_input.get()))).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Green", command= lambda: Green.set_intensity(float(green_input.get()))).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Blue", command= lambda: Blue.set_intensity(float(blue_input.get()))).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=(W, E))


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the names `Red`, `Green`, `Blue` in two way.

One as numbers in the following lines and in `test_pwm_set` function:

```
Red = 0
Green = 0
Blue = 0
```

Another as `RGB_LED` objects in the following lines and in :

```
Red = RGB_LED('Red', 0, 0.0)
Green = RGB_LED('Green', 1, 0.0)
Blue = RGB_LED('Blue', 2, 0.0)

# Buttons
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Red", command= lambda: Red.set_intensity(float(red_input.get()))).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Green", command= lambda: Green.set_intensity(float(green_input.get()))).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Blue", command= lambda: Blue.set_intensity(float(blue_input.get()))).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
```

Use different name.